# J1 waiver grace period

Tags: usa, h1-visa, j-visa

I came to US on a J1 visa (from Jan 1st to Dec 31st, 2020). It got extended until December 31, 2021. However, I want to apply for a waiver so that I can participate in the 2021 visa lottary.

I was told that if I apply for a waiver in the first three months (from the start of my J1 visa), my J1 visa will be canceled. Is this true?

If so, since my visa got renewed (but not started on Jan 1st, 2021), do I still have to wait until April 2021 to file my waiver?

Comment: US visas are only for entering the US. Do you mean that your DS-2019 got extended?

Comment: Yes. I want to participate in h1 b lottory.

Comment: As a J1 visa holder you might be subject to the 2 Year Residency Requirement (section 212e). If you are subject, your visa should indicate that. Please let us know if that's the case and the details of how you obtained the visa (That is, if you have sponsorship from someone, or if you are in the medical field, etc)

Comment: This needs a bit more information for us to be able answer. Edit that in, and I will reopen it.